# How to sort "dated" file directory names in linux

Tags: sorting

I have a directory on server B that contains 'dated' directories like:

```
2015-03-01_10.07.11
2015-03-02_10.05.02
2015-02-25_11.05.02
2015-02-24_11.07.05
```

I need to copy the content of the directory with the latest date.
In my example, I'd have to copy contents of the 2015-03-02_10.05.02 directory.
How would I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `ls -1lr | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 0):

These directories sort correctly according to their names, so you can use the usual `ls -t`   `ls -t` commands to sort them.

So then the problem becomes how to capture the sort and extract the first  (or last). Either an array or a string with regex can do this. There are probably many other ways too. For example look at `find` and `sort` manpages